# Want to Change URL from www.domain.com/home to www.domain.com

Tags: .htaccess

This is my `.htaccess` code:

```
    AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php  
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f  
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /welcome/[/?\s] [NC]    
    RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .php  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /welcome[/?\s] [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f  
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: No luck Sir. I've tried with it. This is my page name which have canonical URL. Whole pages are using canonical URL but on home page I only want to remove /welcome

Comment: What??? Your question says you want to remove `/home` and now you are saying `/welcome`. What is the full URL you tried and what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: Ok I am sending you my htaccess code on root folder

Comment: Read my comment again and see if you have answered both of my questions.

Comment: Yes Sir I know you've responded with /home but at the time of placing code I changed this to /welcome. You can see now my question is containing my htaccess code.

Comment: I provided you your full .htaccess, try it now.

Comment: No sir welcome is page which've added in CMS with slug /welcome or we can say It's a canonical href tag.

Comment: Which CMC it is? Are there CMS specific rewrite rules also?

Comment: Sir it's a concrete 5 CMS. I am working on it very first time. In CakePHP it's providing routes classes itself. But I am stucked in it.

Comment: Concrete5 provides functionality of pretty urls for SEO purpose. Which worked. By using this all my urls were SEO friendly. Code removed index.php from URLs. But for only welcome page I need to remove /welcome

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not for `http://www.lakeshorecc.ca/welcome` URI?

Comment: It is enabled. After putting garbage, page is showing Internal Server Error.