# Redirect to special route using .haccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/home`. The default .haccess file was:
Why the following code does not work?

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit.
```

In order to redirect to `home` route, I added the following code to the `.haccess`:

```
# Redirect to example.com/home
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/home" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Now, the .haccess file content is

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php81” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php81 .php .php8 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit.

# Redirect to example.com/home
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.ir$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.ir$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/home" [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

But it does not work and I encounter the following error:

> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

How could I redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/home`?

I searched on the Internet. and found the following question. but it is revert my question.  [Want to Change URL from www.domain.com/home to www.domain.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22706035/want-to-change-url-from-www-domain-com-home-to-www-domain-com)

Comment: `^(.*)$` matches _any_ possible URL path, so it would redirect `/foobar` as well, and also `/home` again, of course. You want to check for an _empty_ URL path, so that would be just `^$`.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks. It works and my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

[@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) solved my problem.

[@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) comment:
`^(.*)$` matches any possible URL path, so it would redirect `/foobar` as well, and also `/home` again, of course. You want to check for an empty URL path, so that would be just ^$.